# Is it possible to power on Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 (2019) without touching the laptop itself?

Tags: usb, laptop, keyboard, bios, asus-laptop

Giving a rundown on my setup, I use the laptop as a desktop and am going for a super clean minimalistic desk. The laptop is mounted to the underside of my desk via a 3D printed cradle I bought off of Etsy; shout out to Daniel over at 5D Print Factory, and the laptop remains plugged in at all times.

**Ports**:

- 1st USB-C/DP used for my external monitor
- 2nd USB-C used for ethernet via an adapter that has a USB-C passthrough
  that is currently unnoccupied.
- 1st USB-A used for externally powered 4-port USB-A hub, from which my
  external keyboard is plugged in
- 2nd USB-A used for wireless mouse dongle

I was wanting to set my keyboard to power on my laptop via USB, but Asus seems to not allow me to access that power option via the Bios, nor can I find it amongst the many Windows-10 menu settings ie. Control Panel, Device Manager, etc. I also don't want to leave my laptop in a an always on state, as I do not believe it would be good for the device over time.

I'm wondering how I might bypass this issue without having to resort to something of a gimmick such as this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSsqOQH4LQQ

If anyone knows of a reasonable solution, please let me know. If it's impossible, I will have to be more forward thinking when I make my next purchase.

Thank you all for your time.

Edit 1: People seem to be giving information that relates to changing APM settings through the BIOS, but APM is not present in any way shape or form. I have concluded for now that WoL and turn-on via external keyboard will not work with my laptop (as someone outside of this forum had suggested to me). I'll continue searching, but for now, it seems I may  be simply stuck with having my laptop in a constant "on" state. Not ideal, but it will have to do. Thanks everybody.

Comment: If your laptop supports USB Type-C you might be able to accomplish this with a docking station connected to your laptop over USB Type-C.  You are more than likely NOT going to find a solution that involves powering a laptop with a USB keyboard. Wake on Lan might be solution, but that involves another device, which probably does not meet your goals.

Comment: Not a solution, but a mitigation - rather then turning off your laptop, why not resort to using suspend and setting your computer to wake from suspend using keyboard - eg as per https://www.intowindows.com/wake-pc-from-sleep-using-keyboard-and-mouse-in-windows-10/  - failing which just put your computer in sleep mode instead?

Comment: Thanks, davidgo. Wake from suspend doesn't seem to work either. I'll have to try the latter. Discouraging to say the least. I had hoped for better from a wonderfully performant laptop such as this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the system to turn on when power is connected to it.
Then setup a normal electrical switch near the keyboard to turn the power on.

So no need to do the gimmick in the video, just set up a normal electrical switch.

You might have to keep a folded paper between the laptop screen and keyboard so it doesn't detect at screen closed.  Personally I use a eraser for the setup.

Turn on when power is connected, setting can be found in the bios

Comment: Also you can also set up a relay switch, for a cleaner approach. Look at this video after half way through the guy explains the relay switch. https://youtu.be/8jeLCQ62vFk. He actually converted his laptop to an all in one,  but you can just set it up externally ( you will not need to open the laptop up)

Comment: Hey, Gokul. I had thought of something like this. Normally there is an APM tab in the BIOS where plenty of options are available to allow for solutions such as this. WoL is also one of these options that is sadly not present. In fact, there is no APM tab to be found in the BIOS of the Asus Zephyrus G14 at all, which is kind of bewildering to me. I wonder why they would take away functionality like that. In any case, thank you for your answer. I will have to use more discretion with future purchases, now that I'm aware such things exist.

Comment: that is really weird, i also didn't know that happened.